# Why is UISegmentedControl turning the blue parts of my image to black?

Tags: swift, image, uisegmentedcontrol, tint

Can anyone tell me why my segmentedcontrol changes colors of the image I set for the segments? When I step through the debugger the image contains black text and a blue dot. But when it is rendered in the simulator the dot is black and not blue:

[image]

Here is a screen shot of the view hierarchy showing the image I set on the segmented control with a blue dot and to the left the rendered view controller with the segmented control with the dot being black.

[image]

I assume this is related to the tint color and possibly how the control handles light and dark mode.

The funny thing is is I set the image to get an image from my image assets, it is fine. But this images was one that is dynamically generated with calls to UIGraphicsImageRenderer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to input from [Tom Harrington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43832/tom-harrington), the problem was I needed to apply the rendering mode to alwaysOriginal for my image - that was the trick!

`let chatImage = UIImage.textEmbeded(image: scaledDotImage, string: "Chat", isImageBeforeText: false).withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)`

[image]