# Black strip appearing on screen when using Segmented Button Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

newbie to Flutter here.

As mentioned above, I keep seeing black strips when I use segmented button
[The black strip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqrgS.png)

Rather weird as it works normally for the second option of the segmented button, but not for the first or third.
[2nd option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcrue.png)
[3rd option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEfnr.png)

I've suspected and tried checking on whether it may be a positioning/layout issue, but it works fine as long as I don't have the 'onSelectionChanged' portion of the code.
[It is fine here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ1oU.png)

I've tried to check stackoverflow for 'black screen/strips in flutter', but I couldn't find much support on this either. I did check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68163218/flutter-annoying-black-stripe-at-the-bottom-of-screen) and also even from the swift side (not sure if its related or not even)[another issue with black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64581582/why-is-uisegmentedcontrol-turning-the-blue-parts-of-my-image-to-black)

The portion of the code is as such:

```
Container(
                  width: width,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                          iconSize: 40,
                          onPressed: () {
                            _controller.previousPage(
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                curve: Curves.easeIn);
                          },
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.navigate_before)),
                      SegmentedButton(
                        segments: const <ButtonSegment<Options>>[
                          ButtonSegment<Options>(
                              value: Options.options1, label: Text('op1')),
                          ButtonSegment<Options>(
                              value: Options.options2, label: Text('op2')),
                          ButtonSegment<Options>(
                              value: Options.options1, label: Text('op3'))
                        ],
                        selected: selection,
                        onSelectionChanged: (Set<Options> newSelection) {
                          setState(() {
                            selection = newSelection;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                          iconSize: 40,
                          onPressed: () {
                            _controller.nextPage(
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                curve: Curves.easeIn);
                          },
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.navigate_next)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                )
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: Seems to have found the issue - I'm running Flutter in a Linux VM, causing rendering issues. Will continue to update this on further workarounds!